# Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

i purchased "wordpress for joomla " extension and now i am not able to install it in my jooma site (version 1.5.23).While instaalling displays a message like
 "
JFTP::login: Unable to login
JClientHelper::setCredentialsFromRequest failed
 Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package " .Anyone please help !

Comment: Probably you need to unzip the kit and then install the component.

Comment: Thanx for the reply .But i have unziped it already. :(

Comment: Do you use the FTP connection ? If yes you should check the credentials in your config file.

Comment: no havn't used ftp connection.Kevin ,could you please make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Your FTP information are maybe wrong. Go in the administration/Config and check ftp informations.

You're also using an old Joomla version : update and prepare to Joomla 2.5!